For $f$ Lipschitz with $|\nabla f| = 1$ a.e., what is the supremal Hausdorff dimension of the set on which $\varepsilon< |\nabla f| < 1-\varepsilon$?
Let $f$ be a Lipschitz function with $|\nabla f| = 1$ almost everywhere.
Let $\varepsilon \geq 0$. What is the supremal Hausdorff dimension of the set on which $f$ is differentiable with $\varepsilon < |\nabla f| < 1-\varepsilon$?
Motivation:
The question can be interchangably phrased in terms of measurable sets, which may be more natural.
Let $A \subset \mathbb R$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. We can consider its topological interior, exterior, and boundary, but often times for badly behaved sets it is more natural to consider the "measure theoretic" version of these concepts instead.
By the Lebesgue density theorem, almost every point of $A$ is a point of measure theoretic density $1$ and almost every point of $A^c$ is a point of density $0$.
It is thus natural to define the measure theoretic interior
as the points of density $1$, and the exterior as those of density $0$. On the other hand, the natural definition of measure theoretic boundary in terms of density is as all those points of density $\frac{1}{2}$.
It turns out there are always such points of density $\frac{1}{2}$ unless $A$ is the whole space, or empty up to a null set. Thus a measurable set of nonzero but not full measure always has a measure theoretic boundary.
To see the relevance to this problem, lets call eikonal any Lipschitz function with $|f'| = 1$ almost everywhere. Then $f$ can be written as an antiderivative of $1_A - 1_{A^c}$ for some measurable set $A$. Conversely, to every measurable set $A$ corresponds a unique (up to an additive constant) eikonal function.
As such questions about the derivative of $f$ reduce to questions about the associated set $A := \{f' = 1\}$.

Points where $f$ is differentiable are points where the density of $A$ exists.
Points where $f' = 1, 0 -1$ are measure theoretic interior, boundary, and exterior points respectively.

The question is thus asking what happens at the exceptional points
that are not an interior, exterior or boundary. In particular, how big can the set be where the density exists but is not a measure theoretic interior, exterior, or boundary?
Finally, we note that the question on Lipschitz functions
can be asked for functions on $\mathbb R^n$ as well, where it is likely to not reduce to sets in a straightforward way since we no longer have the representation as the antiderivative of $1_A -1_{A^c}$.
